# How is damage redirected from a Star Spawn Hulk's Psychic Mirror?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, damage

Related to my [other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/124083/19580) about this feature.

The **[Star Spawn Hulk](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/star-spawn-hulk)** has a feature called *Psychic Mirror*, which reads:

> ***Psychic Mirror.*** If the hulk takes psychic damage, each creature within 10 feet of the hulk takes that damage instead; the hulk takes none of the damage.

The **[Star Spawn Seer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/star-spawn-seer)**, which is commonly present around a **Hulk**, has attacks that deal psychic damage, clearly meant to be aimed at the Hulk  to be dished out (particularly, ***Psychic Orb*** which deals 27 (5d10) psychic damage at range).

My question:

**Say my Seer hits my Hulk with that attack, and there are 3 creatures within 10 feet of the Hulk. How much damage does each creature take? The full 27 (5d10), or is the damage divided among the recipients?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Each creature takes the damage completely

The language is direct in that (my emphasis)

> **each creature** within 10 feet of the hulk takes that damage instead

This is identical language to *[Fireball](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fireball)*(emphasis mine):

> **Each creature** in a 20-foot-radius sphere centered on that point must make a Dexterity saving throw. A target takes 8d6 fire damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.

In both cases, each creature is required to take the damage delivered by the spell. There is no pool of damage that is shared.

Note that *[Sleep](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sleep)* does have a mechanic of a pool:

> Starting with the creature that has the lowest current hit points, each creature affected by this spell falls unconscious until the spell ends, the sleeper takes damage, or someone uses an action to shake or slap the sleeper awake. Subtract each creature's hit points from the total before moving on to the creature with the next lowest hit points. A creature's hit points must be equal to or less than the remaining total for that creature to be affected.

Answer (score 5):

## The total damage that would have been dealt the the Hulk is dealt to each creature in range

Because the effect does not specify that the damage be divided among creatures within range, the full damage is dealt to each creature within range.

An example of an effect that *would* divide among multiple creatures within range is the Life Cleric's Channel Divinity:

> Choose any creatures within 30 feet of you, and divide those hit points among them.